Could we approximate $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^4}dx$ using a Riemann sum?
We know that in one dimension, the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\left(1/x^{4}\right){\rm d}x$ is not finite. But could we approximate this integral using a Riemann Sum ?.

In particular, if we divide the interval $\left[0,1\right]$ into equal-length partitions
$$
0 = x_{0} \leq x_{1} \leq \cdots \leq x_{n} = 1\quad \mbox{with}\quad \Delta_{i} = \left\vert x_{i}-x_{i-1}\right\vert = \frac{1}{n}\,\,\, \forall\ 1\leq i\leq n
$$
Do we have $\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta_if(x_{i})$ converge to $\int_{1/n}^{1}\left(1/x^{4}\right){\rm d}x$ as $n\to \infty\ ?$.
Could we give a bound on the difference
$$
\left\vert\int_{1/n}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{4}}\,{\rm d}x
- \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{\left(k/n\right)^{4}}\frac{1}{n}\right\vert
$$
to get the rate of convergence of the Riemann sum as $n\to \infty$ ?.

Thank you very much for any of your helps or useful references !.

Since the integral diverges, the expression $\big|\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^4}dx-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(\frac{k}{n})^4}\frac{1}{n}\big|$ makes no sense

In particular $\int\limits_0^{1/n} \frac{1}{x^4},dx$ is infinite for all $n$ so subtracting the finite $\frac1{(\frac{1}{n})^4}\frac{1}{n}$ will leave the difference infinite.

I can grasp the idea of what you mean and I love it. However, since there is no definition of the expression $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^4}dx$, the question is getting a bit meaningless as it stands. You need to replace $0$ as a vanishing positive function of $n$ instead to make it meaningful. For example, you can instead write $\int_{1/n}^{1}\frac{1}{x^4}dx$ or $\int_{1/n^2}^{1}\frac{1}{x^4}dx$ and then you can extract some meaningful results.

Yes as @mertunsal say, transform the problematic $0$ by a function tending to 0.

Perhaps you mean $\left|\int_{1/n}^1 \frac{1}{x^4}dx-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(\frac{k}{n})^4}\frac{1}{n}\right|$?

Thanks for your comment! Now I realize the difference dose not really make sense, and I have edited the question according to your suggestion. @mertunsal

Thanks! I have modified the question, now hopefully the difference should make sense! @jjagmath

As now formulated, the absolute value is $|\frac{1}{3}(n^3-1) - c(n)n^3|$ with the sequence $c$ converging to $\zeta(4) = \pi^4/90$ as $n\to\infty$. Qualitatively, the right-hand Riemann is not a good approximator of the integral....

I see! I think this bound makes sense to me, thanks for your comment!@AndrewD.Hwang

tl; dr: Perhaps surprisingly, the stated Riemann sums do not converge to the integral at all.
Calculus guarantees that "Riemann sums converge to the integral" if the interval of integration is fixed. Here, by contrast, the integrand blows up so rapidly at $0$ that the right-hand Riemann sum over $[0, 1]$ with $n$ equal-length subintervals (a.k.a. the left-hand Riemann sum over $[\frac{1}{n}, 1 + \frac{1}{n}]$) is only accurate to $O(n^{3})$. (We might instead consider the left-hand Riemann sum over $[\frac{1}{n}, 1]$ with $(n - 1)$ subintervals, but the analysis below is effectively unchanged.)
In detail, for each positive integer $n$, we have
$$
E_{n}
:= \biggl|\int_{1/n}^{1} \frac{1}{x^{4}}\, dx - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(\frac{k}{n})^{4}}\, \frac{1}{n}\biggr|
= n^{3} \biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{4}}\biggr) - \tfrac{1}{3}(n^{3} - 1).
$$
(The sum exceeds the integral for every $n$, so we may drop the absolute value by swapping the terms.) Since
$$
1 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{4}}
  \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{4}}
  = \zeta(4)
  = \frac{\pi^{4}}{90}
  \approx 1.08+
$$
for every positive integer $n$, we have
$$
\frac{2}{3}n^{3} + \frac{1}{3} \leq E_{n} = n^{3} \biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{4}}\biggr) - \frac{1}{3}(n^{3} - 1)
\leq \biggl(\frac{\pi^{4}}{90} - \frac{1}{3}\biggr) n^{3} + \frac{1}{3}.
$$
Particularly, $|E_{n}| \approx O(n^{3})$ as $n \to \infty$, and the constant in the lower bound increases toward $\frac{\pi^{4}}{90} - \frac{1}{3}$ like $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{4}} \approx O(\frac{1}{n^{3}})$.

Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! I think it really makes sense and now I understand! Could I also ask, since we have $\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{1}{3}\approx O(\frac{1}{n^3}),$ doesn't this imply that $E_n\leq O(1),$ which will be bounded?

There are two asymptotics in play: The finite sum of $1/k^4$ approaches $\zeta(4)$ like $O(1/n^3)$; and the difference between the integral and Riemann sums, which grows like $O(n^3)$ with constant $\zeta(4) - (1/3)$ (and not by any smaller constant). It's the second that you asked about. The first measures the size of a coefficient of $n^3$. In retrospect it was confusing for me to mention at all, especially in the second half of the last sentence. :)

The Riemann integral $\int_0^1{x^{-4}}$ exists but is infinite. It is thus not completely clear what qualifies as a good approximation. You say to look at $\int_{1/n}^{1}{x^{-4}}$ instead, however this is arbitrary and other choices could be taken as proxies.
I will clarify. Let $\varphi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $0 < \varphi < 1$  and $\varphi \to 0$ with $n$. Additionally, let $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ where $\phi \uparrow +\infty$ with $n$. Consider generally
$$I_n^{(m)}(\varphi) := \int\limits_{\varphi(n)}^{1}{x^{-m}}\,\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{m-1}\Big(\frac{1}{{\varphi(n)}^{m-1}} - 1\Big),$$
where $m > 1$, as the proxy to $I^{(m)} := \int_{0}^{1}{x^{-m}}$. As Riemann sums of $I^{(m)}$ take
$$s_n^{(m)}(\phi) := {\phi(n)}^{m-1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\phi(n)}{k^{-m}} = {\phi(n)}^{m-1}\mathrm{H}_{\phi(n)}^{(m)}.$$
Here $\mathrm{H}_{\phi(n)}^{(m)}$ denotes the $\phi(n)$-th harmonic number of order $m$.
Think now of $\phi$ having been fixed as a function, satisfying the criteria above. Then we can make the error $\mathrm{E}_n^{(m)}(\varphi, \phi) := I_n^{(m)}(\varphi) - s_n^{(m)}(\phi)$ even vanish by solving the algebraic equation $\mathrm{E}_n^{(m)}(\varphi, \phi) = 0$ for $\varphi(n)$. The solution is
$$\varphi(n) := {[(m - 1) {\phi(n)}^{m-1} \mathrm{H}_{\phi(n)}^{(m)} + 1]}^{-\frac{1}{m-1}}$$
which you may verify to satisfy the crieria for $\varphi$ from above.
Worse approximations come from switching the harmonic numbers $\mathrm{H}_{\phi(n)}^{(m)}$ in $\varphi(n)$ with some $\alpha(n, m)$. In particular, the error will be
$$\mathrm{E}_n^{(m)}(\varphi(\alpha), \phi) = {\phi(n)}^{m-1} [\alpha(n, m) - \mathrm{H}_{\phi(n)}^{(m)}].$$
So to get a convergent approximation, in the sense that the limit wrt $n$ is zero, $\alpha$ would need to be a strictly better approximation than $\mathrm{o}(\phi(n)^{-(m-1)})$ to the harmonic numbers.
One choice to consider is the limit of harmonic numbers of order $m$, i.e. $\lim_n{\mathrm{H}_{\phi(n)}^{(m)}} = \zeta(m)$. Thus
$$\varphi(n; \alpha=\zeta(m)) := [(m - 1) {\phi(n)}^{m-1} \zeta(m) + 1]^{-\frac{1}{m-1}}$$
where the only non-constant part wrt $n$ is $\phi(n)$. So, in our example, as $m := 4$ and $\zeta(4) = \pi^4/90$ and $\phi(n) = n$, we get
$$ \varphi(n; \zeta(4)) := \Big( \frac{\pi^4}{30} n^3 + 1 \Big)^{-\frac{1}{3}}, $$
not quite the bare $1/n$ as in the OP. The error will be
$$\mathrm{E}_n^{(4)}(\varphi(n; \zeta(4)), \phi=n) = n^3 [\zeta(4) - \mathrm{H}_{n}^{(4)}].$$
We have the expansion $\mathrm{H}_{n}^{(4)} = \zeta(4) - 1/(3n^3) + \mathrm{O}(1/n^4)$, therefore
$$\mathrm{E}_n^{(4)}(\varphi(n; \zeta(4)), n) = n^3 \Big[\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{n^3} + \mathrm{O}(1/n^4)\Big] = \frac{1}{3} + \mathrm{O}(1/n).$$
Hence, this combination is not convergent, but for large values of $n$ we expect the error to be around $1/3$. It also follows that no other constant besides $\alpha(m=4) = \zeta(4)$ will lead to lead to such "constant-away" errors. If $c \neq \zeta(4)$ is any constant, we will get the term $(c - \zeta(4))n^3$ which implies $\mathrm{\Omega}(n^3)$ error growth. Same is true for $\alpha(n, m)$ of the form $c + o(1)$. And if $\varphi(n; \alpha) = 1/n$ as in your question, then $\alpha(n, m=4) = 1/3 - 1/(3n^3)$ is of this form with $c = 1/3$. So your approximaton grows as $\mathrm{\Omega}(n^3)$, in accordance with Andrew D. Hwang's answer.

"The Riemann integral exists but is infinite": no, it doesn't exist, according to these three definitions. What definition of Riemann integral are you using?

@TonyK Almost the same definition as you, likely. Of course, the final condition needs to change to accomadate the blow up. It is similar to how we have the usual epsilon-delta limit definition for finite limits, and then a separate definition for when the limit is infinite. Note the difference between "Riemann integral exists" and "function is Riemann-integrable". These are separate things with the latter also requiring that the Riemann integral is finite. Exactly analogous to derivatives. A derivative may be infinite but to be differentiable the derivative must be finite. And so on.

First link: "Riemann integrals can be computed only for proper integrals", where a proper integral requires that "the integrand does not approach infinity at any point in the range of integration." Second link: see sentence beginning "To be specific..." Third link: "$\int_0^1(1/x)dx$ isn't defined as a Riemann integral because $f$ is unbounded." I rest my case!

@TonyK Your first quote has "can be computed". Of course, we do not "compute" infinite limits. The second complete quote is «To be specific, we say that "the Riemann integral of f exists and equals s"». What is being defined is thus "Riemann integral exists AND equals s". Since "s" was a real number, no surprise that the infinite case is not encompassed. Your third link, doesn't actually define the Riemann integral. It defines, see definition 1.3, "A bounded function is Riemann integrable...". I emphasised the difference between "exists"/"integrable" in my first comment. Your case is dead.

@TonyK About Riemann sums where $\delta_i$ are interval lengths and $x_{i-1} + \varepsilon_i \delta_i$ gives position of the tag element from previous mesh node: «Hat sie nun die Eigenschaft, wie auch $\delta$ und $\varepsilon$ gewählt werden mögen, sich einer festen Grenze $A$ unendlich zu nähern, sobald sämmtliche delta unendlich klien werden, so heisst dieser Werth $\int_a^b{f(x)} dx$.» (Riemann, 1868) I emphasize: «einer fester Grenze $A$» ("fixed limit $A$"), not «einer festen Zahl $A$» ("fixed number $A$").

@TonyK As a week has passed, I consider this discussion closed. Good fortunes to you.
